# Express.Js response.download not reacting to client-side abort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

When aborting a request to an express.js application, that is currently responding with `response.download`, the express.js application waits for a timeout rather than canceling the request (or throwing an error, or doing anything).

The provided callback function is also not called until this timeout is reached.

#### Client Code

```
const abortController = new AbortController();
const request = axios.get('/file', {
  signal: controller.signal,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
abortController.abort();
```

#### Express.js

```
const app = Express();
app.get('/file', (req, res) => {
  res.download(path, name, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send();
    }
  });
});
```

### Browser Differences

In Firefox, resending the request from the client will result in a wait until the aborted request timed out. If the file is above a certain threshold in size, the request gets canceled immediately and no wait time before the next request starts (this is the desired behaviour).

In Chrome, resending the request will continue the previous aborted request.
This also holds true for Opera and seems to be a Chromium feature.

I don't want any of this behaviour. I want the request to be canceled immediately, and after requesting again to be started from the beginning.

I know, that the above code will error, because `res.status(500).send()` cannot resend headers. But my concern is the timeout / not immediate cancel of requests.

Comment: This might also be because axios is not properly aborting the request.